# Find a subspace such that the quadratic form is always positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(x)=2x_1^2-2x_1x_2-12x_1x_3-2x_2^2-8x_2x_3-x_3^2$. How to find a two dimensional subspace $V$ of $R^3$ such that $\forall 0 \neq x \in V: f(x)>0$?

I diagonalized the matrix of the quadratic form but I don't understand what to do next in order to find a subspace that satisfies the condition since $f(x)=0 \wedge f(y)=0 \nRightarrow f(x+y)=0$.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: I assume you wrote $f(x) = x^T A x$, where $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & -6 \\ -1 & -2 & -4\\ -6 & -4 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, and diagonalized $A$, correct? What are the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$? How many strictly positive eigenvalues did you find? $f(x) > 0$ when $x \neq 0$ belongs to the span of eigenvectors with strictly positive eigenvalues.